# Is this proper use of HTML5?

Tags: html

Please take a look at this example -
[image]

I know I'm using the `footer/nav` correctly but the `<side>` and `<section>` is kinda confusing.

The `<figure>` will be just one huge logo. Beside that will be the main content. Would `<aside>` be proper use? Its not side content like a sidebar so thats why i'm asking.

Also the `<section>` would be columns for the content, would that be right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<aside>` - content that is considered separate from the main content of the page

You could put the main content inside an `<article>` element.

`<figure>` - for diagrams, illustrations, photos, and code examples

Since a logo is not a stand-alone unit, I wouldn't use the FIGURE element. Consider just setting that image as a page background or something - it's just one image, so there is no need for much markup here.

`<article>` - could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content
Source: http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/

Comment: I thought article would be used for long paragraphs.

Comment: @Trippy I've updated my answer. For example, on this page, the ARTICLE element could be used to wrap your question - including the title, answers, comments, ...

Comment: Thanks. After reading HTML5doctor and the W3C it makes sense now.

Answer (score 4):

HTML first of all gives *meaning* to content. The `<aside>` element is for ["sort of but not really related content."](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-aside-element) You shouldn't put your *main* content in it. A `<div>` or `<article>` element should do fine. Position it *on the side* using CSS.

Comment: article would really be proper to put in?

Comment: @Trippy Possibly. I suggest you read [the specification and examples](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html) to find the proper structuring. When in doubt, keep it simple.